# List elements of these sets:

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I am studying for a discrete mathematics exam, and I have trouble answering solving the following:

- List 3 element of $\left( \mathbb R \times \mathbb Q \right) \setminus \left( \mathbb Q \times \mathbb Q \right)$.

Is this meant to be solved with the identity that states that given set $A$ and set $B$, $A \setminus B = A \cap B^\complement$ ? Can someone explain the mathematical reasoning needed to answer this problem? I think that the answers should be tuples with two elements: $(x, y)$, where $x$ will be an element of $\mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q$. If we remove the rationals from the real numbers, only irrationals remain and thus the solutions should look something like

$(\pi, y_1), (e, y_2) (\sqrt{2}, y_3)$ etc.

My biggest problem (considering that these assumptions are correct) is that I have no clue as to how to figure the $y$ elements for each tuple, and I am afraid that its because I really do not know the mathematical concept behind this.

Comment: Without formating I can not understand your question.  I don't understand what (x1,y1)(x2,y2)(x3,y3) can possibly mean in a set context.  If you subtract the rationals from the reals the *ir*rationals are left.  RxQ-QxQ will be the ordered pairs where the first term is irrational and the second is rational.  I don't know what "(RxQ)-(QxQ)(x1,y1)(x2,y2)(x3,y3)" can possibly mean.

Comment: The added (x1, y1) etc are in the question, they left a space for me to fill in the answers with 3 tupples. Thats what they are for, the actual question is just (RxQ) - (QxQ)  and they ask me to list 3 tupples. Actual numeric samples. Since I have the answer key I see they have listed (pi, 2/3) (square root of two, -9/3)  as answers.

Comment: @fleablood would you plese see my last comment for this question. I understand that the difference between the real numbers and the rational would be the irrational numbers, however i dont understand how that logic is applied to this problem, I mean, what are the logical steps to follow, following the same principle then the difference between Q and Q would be the null set?

Comment: First of all, welcome to MSE! I formatted your post to be more readable and added an answer below. For future reference, you can find a short introduction to MathJax (which allows you to type mathematical formulas in the way I did) [over here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Don't hesitate to ask for clarification if my answer doesn't satisfy your needs.

Comment: Specific rationals $y_i$, please.

Comment: The ys can be any rationals.  RxQ are any ordered pair where x is real and y is rational.  QxQ is any ordered pair where x is rational and y is real.  So RxQ - QxQ is any ordered pairs where x is real and y is rational except the ones where x is rational and y is rational... that leaves the ones where x is irrational and y is rational.

Answer (score 1):

Let us proceed in steps: We want to find elements of $\mathbb R \times \mathbb Q \setminus \left( \mathbb Q \times \mathbb Q \right)$. So our desired elements are of the form $(x,y)$ where

1. $x \in \mathbb R$,
2. $y \in \mathbb Q$ and
3. $(x,y) \not \in \mathbb Q \times \mathbb Q$

This is equivalent to $x \in \mathbb R$, $y \in \mathbb Q$ and $x \not \in \mathbb Q$. (Since $(x,y) \not \in \mathbb Q \times \mathbb Q$ if and only if $x \not \in \mathbb Q$ or $y \not \in \mathbb Q$ and we know that $y \in \mathbb Q$.)

So any pair $(x,y)$ where $x$ is a real number that is not a rational and $y$ is a rational will do. Examples are $(\pi,0), (e, \frac{1}{2}), (\sqrt{2}, -2), (\frac{7 \pi}{5}, \frac{2}{3}), \ldots$

In fact, we proved that $\left( \mathbb R \times \mathbb Q \right) \setminus \left(\mathbb Q \times \mathbb Q \right) = \left(\mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q \right) \times \mathbb Q$.